# Circuit with a threshold

Tags: electromagnetism

Can there be a circuit or a device(probably a semiconductor) which allow flow of current only at a minimum threshold voltage?

I've heard about comparator but I am not able to understand how they work(their internal structure and circuitry).

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Have you heard of diodes?

Comment: [Semiconductor diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Semiconductor_diodes) in general, and [Zener diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode) sepecifically do something like that, but only imperfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option here is a Zener diode, which is a type of a diode with a well controlled breakdown voltage achieved by a particular doping profile.

When a Zener is reverse biased, the current is very low until the reverse voltage gets to a specific level, after which the current sharply increases.

This sharp current increase is similar to that of a regular forward biased diode, but you have flexibility of choosing threthold voltage level.

Answer (score 0):

> I've heard about comparator but I am not able to understand how they work

A [comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator) is a complex electronic circuit that measures the difference between two different input voltages, and which switches its output either to a high voltage, or to a low voltage depending on which of its two inputs is at a higher voltage than the other.

A comparator does not allow any current to flow from its inputs to its output.  Instead, the current at the output must come from/return to an external power supply.

A comparator whose one input is a [voltage reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_reference), and whose other input is the voltage that you wish to measure *might* be what you are looking for, but without a more complete description of your application, it's hard to say for certain.